# Cake bake (Cake Php 2.6) error in php 5.6.32 In Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cakephp

I am using php version 5.6 Both in my windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Dual boot) Laptop

cake bake (cake-php version 2.6) working fine in my windows but When I try to ./cake bake in my Ubuntu it gives the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/MY_APP/lib/Cake/Utility/String.php on line 24

After Googling I know that if create problem only php 7 But I am running php 5.6.32 and It working well in my windows But why is it not working in my Ubuntu?

Comment: You are _not_ running PHP 5.6 in your Ubuntu environment. Maybe you have 5.6 installed _too_, but CakePHP obviously uses the 7.x variant, as otherwise that error wouldn't show up. To figure which binary is being used you can for example check the `PHP_BINARY` constant in a CakePHP shell, I'm pretty sure that it will point to the 7.x one.

Comment: @ndm Thank you for your Reply :) .You are right. >> php  -i command showing  .... 

phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

although in browser if i run phpinfo(); it showing I am using php 5.6.32 

What is the point ..?

So,How can I fix the problem .... I am new in Ubuntu :) ... Thank you in advance .

Comment: You can uninstall PHP 7, and install PHP 5.6 using `apt-get`. https://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: This guide shows how to run both versions: https://lornajane.net/posts/2016/php-7-0-and-5-6-on-ubuntu